# Как описать домен в настройках bind?

Tags: debian, dns

У меня есть сервер (Debian 8). Так же есть два ns - ***ns1.w4u.com.ua*** и ***ns2.w4u.com.ua***, которые ссылаются на сервер. У регистратора доменного имени я прописал эти сервера для домена ***soshichnezosh.com***. Но домен не показывается. Спросил у регистратора, вот их ответ

```
Добрый день.

На указанных NS-серверах нет записей о домене:

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-3ubuntu0.8-Ubuntu <<>> @NS1.W4U.COM.UA soshichnezosh.com any
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 9947
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;soshichnezosh.com. IN  ANY


Обратитесь, пожалуйста, к держателю NS-серверов, чтобы они завели
записи о домене в файл зоны.
```

Как сконфигурировать *bind* для того, чтобы домен прошёл регистрацию?

Comment: вы после внесения в конфигурацию NS настроек для домена soshichnezosh.com - выполняли перезапуск сервера имён? `rndc reload`. Это если не считая варианта ошибки в конфигурации :)

Comment: надо описать зону. пример есть в той же самой инструкции, ссылку на которую вы приводили в предыдущем вашем вопросе.

Comment: извините, но можете прям "носом тыкнуть" где там об этом написано, не могу понять

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добрый день. Так как NS-сервера администрируете Вы, то Вам нужно создавать файл-зоны на сервере, где развернут bind и куда направлены NS, для доменного имени soshichnezosh.com, где Вы укажите SOA-запись и все другие необходимые записи для домена (А, МХ, CNAME, NS). Файл-зоны Вы создаете в /var/named/soshichnezosh.com.zone (это для bind9). Пример:

```
$TTL 6000
@   IN  SOA     ns1.w4u.com.ua. admine-mai.w4u.com.ua. (
        2016061401  
        3600        ;Refresh
        1800        ;Retry
        604800      ;Expire
        86400       ;Minimum TTL
)
; Указываем два name сервера
        IN  NS      ns1.w4u.com.ua.
        IN  NS      ns1.w4u.com.ua.


; Определяем IP адреса name серверов
ns1     IN  A       1.1.1.1
ns2     IN  A       2.2.2.2

; Define hostname -> IP нашего сервера для этого домена
@       IN  A       3.3.3.3
www     IN  A       3.3.3.3
```

Далее Вам в конфиге, а именно в /etc/named.conf нужно указать, что файл soshichnezosh.com.zone есть файлом конфигурации для домена soshichnezosh.com. Также нужно указать тип сервера (master or slave).Пример:

```
zone "soshichnezosh.com" IN {
            type master;
            file "soshichnezosh.com.zone";
};
```

После проверяйте опрашивается ли домен по Вашим NS. Проверить можете выполнив такую команду

```
dig soshichnezosh.com @ns1.w4u.com.ua
```

Это минимальные настройки которые нужны. IP указаны для примера

Comment: сделал, все как вы написали. последняя команда вывела такое

    ; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-9+deb8u6-Debian <<>> soshichnezosh.com     @ns1.w4u.com.ua
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 57565
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;soshichnezosh.com.  IN A

;; Query time: 224 msec
;; SERVER: 5.9.39.171#53(5.9.39.171)
;; WHEN: Tue Jun 14 17:09:52 CEST 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 46

Comment: но домен не заработал

Comment: Можете предоставить пример файла /etc/named.conf и /var/named/soshichnezosh.com.zone? и уточните версию bind

Comment: версия bind - BIND 9.9.5-9+deb8u6-Debian (Extended Support Version)

Comment: /etc/named.conf - zone "soshichnezosh.com" IN {
            type master;
            file "/var/named/soshichnezosh.com.zone";
};

Comment: /var/named/soshichnezosh.com.zone - $TTL 6000
@   IN  SOA     ns1.w4u.com.ua. admin.w4u.com.ua. (
        2016061401  
        3600        ;Refresh
        1800        ;Retry
        604800      ;Expire
        86400       ;Minimum TTL
)
; Указываем два name сервера
        IN  NS      ns1.w4u.com.ua.
        IN  NS      ns2.w4u.com.ua.


; Определяем IP адреса name серверов
ns1     IN  A       5.9.39.171
ns2     IN  A       5.9.39.171

; Define hostname -> IP нашего сервера для этого домена
@       IN  A       5.9.39.171
www     IN  A       5.9.39.171

Comment: Проверила, так как у Вас на сервере Debian 8,то там пути отличаются от тех, которые привела в ответе. Путь к "главному" named.conf - /etc/bind/named.conf.options. Здесь указывается список диапазонов IP,которые могут запрашивать домен. А здесь /etc/bind/named.conf.local уже добавляете саму зону (Это zone "soshichnezosh.com" IN {
            type master;
            file "soshichnezosh.com.zone";
};) А здесь /etc/bind/zones/nixway/soshichnezosh.com.zone указываете SOA и другие записи

Comment: у меня вот такое там  - http://paste.debian.net/739165/

Comment: allow-query { any; }; - это говорит о том,что разрешены запросы с всех диапазонов IP. Теперь главное Вам добавить саму зону в  /etc/bind/named.conf.local и создать файл зоны и указать SOA и др.записи в /etc/bind/zones/nixway/soshichnezosh.com.zone

Comment: спасибо, все заработало

Comment: Была рада помочь :) Все действительно работает, А и NS при dig отдаются

Answer (score 1):

вам надо описать мастер-зону `soshichnezosh.com.`. для каждой зоны необходим отдельный файл. местоположение непринципиально, лишь бы резервные копии было удобно делать.

например, пусть для хранения зонных файлов будет каталог `/etc/bind/masters`, а зона будет храниться в одноимённом файле (вообще имя тоже может быть произвольным). [ориентировочно](http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch6/mydomain.html) примерно так:

```
$ cat /etc/bind/masters/soshichnezosh.com
$TTL 86400
$ORIGIN soshichnezosh.com.

@               IN      SOA     ns1.w4u.com.ua. hostmaster.w4u.com.ua. (
        2016061401      ; Serial
                3H      ; Refresh
                15      ; Retry
                1w      ; Expire
                3h      ; Negative Cache TTL
)

  IN  NS  ns1.w4u.com.ua.
  IN  NS  ns2.w4u.com.ua.
  IN  A   1.1.1.1
```

в *a-записи*, естественно, подставьте актуальный ip-адрес, в который будет резолвиться имя `soshichnezosh.com.`.

---

для того, чтобы этот файл был «учтён» программой *bind*, где-то в конфигурации его надо упомянуть. ориентировочно примерно так:

```
zone "soshichnezosh.com" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/masters/soshichnezosh.com";
};
```

если у вас будет не одна зона, удобно поместить все эти упоминания мастре-зон в отдельный файл (их может быть много в одном файле, в отличие от самого описания зоны). например, `/etc/bind/master-zones.conf`.

а в конце главного конфигурационного файла (`/etc/bind/named.conf`) добавить строчку про этот файл:

```
include "/etc/bind/master-zones.conf";
```

---

смысл приведённой в зонном файле информации изложен во множестве руководств (ну, помимо «первоисточника» — соответствующих *rfc*). начать можно, например, с [википедийной статьи](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone_file).